# How to go through empty excel cells and selectively use function (or a work around)?

Tags: excel

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrsH7.png

I have on excel what is shown above. What I need is to fill in the Row and Column columns with the values in the head of the column that the value to their left is in. What this means is that for D001-01 the Row value is 1 and the column value is also one.

For D001-02 Row=1 Column=2

For D001-03 Row=1 Column=2

For D002-01 Row=1 Column=1

And so on. Is there any good way I can do this? My real lists are very long, this is just a simplified example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`MATCH` function](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/MATCH-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca), searching for `"*"` to get any non-empty cell, to get a number for the column that is not empty in the row. Then, you can use the `INDIRECT` function to convert that into a reference to the corresponding column heading. Then, use `FIND` to find the index of the 'X' along with `LEFT` to get the row value or `RIGHT` and `LEN` to get the column value.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean...using the match column would require me to manually select each value that I want to match, wouldn't it?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I'm working on figuring out how to use 'INDIRECT' right now. I'll let you know how it goes when I figure it out!